# Django manytomany field is absent in modelform

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have following Model

```
 class Member(models.Model):
        name = ...
        qualities = models.ManyToManyField(ProfessionalQuality, related_name='members')
```

And following form:

```
class CommonMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This form for gathering common features in both admin and member forms
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommonMemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['qualities'].validators.append(...)
```

When I try to instantiate form, I get KeyError: 'qualities' are not in self.fields. Why is that?
This code works in admin.

What is the correct way of handling such fields?

Comment: how is defined ProtectedManyToManyField ? I mean this is not a Django field type

Comment: This is bare extension of ManyToManyField. I will update the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CommonMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This form for gathering common features in both admin and member forms
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
          'qualities': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommonMemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['qualities'].widget...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class CommonMemberForm(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegularUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('qualities').validators = [validate_qualities]
```